# My list dependent from an array flip only once, but in the console it keeps reversing

Tags: reactjs

I get an array and apply the reverse method on it. but for some reason it flips only 1 time, although in the console it flips like it should be

```
function BasicTable(props) {
  const tabKey = props.contentDataKey;
  const arrKey = props.content; //array []

  const [newArr, setnewArr] = useState(arrKey);

  console.log(newArr);
  return (
    <div>
      <List className="ListHead">
        <ListItem>Id</ListItem>
        <ListItem
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("zxc");
            arrKey.reverse();
            console.log(arrKey);
            setnewArr(arrKey);
          }}
        >
          {tabKey.firstRowText}
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>{tabKey.secondRowText}</ListItem>
        <ListItem> {tabKey.thirdRowtext}</ListItem>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      {!isEmpty(arrKey) &&
        arrKey.map((row, i) => (
          <List className="Listbody">
            <ListItem align="left">{i + 1}</ListItem>
            <ListItem>{row[tabKey.firstRowKey]}</ListItem>
         ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reverse method mutates the array, and you cannot mutate your props

```
const arrKey = props.content.slice().reverse();
```

You can use slice to make a copy, and store it somewhere

Or if you want to reverse only when clicking the button:

```
setnewArr(arrKey.slice().reverse());
```

You are also mapping from the props array, maybe you meant to map from the state:

```
newArr.map((row, i) => (
```

To see the reversed results

Comment: I kept everything(even map array from the props),  just changed onClick func like this and its all works , but i have no idea how  `onClick={() => {
            arrKey.reverse();
            setnewArr(arrKey.slice());
          }} `